# Generic Makefile doesn't parse command correctly

Tags: c, makefile

In my shcool we have repetive projects and workshop that have a similar architecture.
I'm trying to write a generic makefile that would execute any subrules in any subdirectories but also execute specific rules in every sub directory.
I'm currently stuck when trying to make any subrule in any subdirectory.

Here is the parent makefile:

```
# Documentation for the Makefile
# ------------------------------
# Usage:
# - To build 'all' target in all subdirectories: make
# - To invoke a specific target in all subdirectory: make [target]
#   Example: make clean
# - To invoke a specific target in a specific subdirectory: make [subdirectory]:[target]
#   Example: make subdir_name:clean

# Compiler for project
CC = gcc

# Compiler flags used when compiling every binary or library
CFLAGS = -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -D_GNU_SOURCE

# Compiler flags used when compiling tests
DFLAGS = -lgcov -fPIC -g3 --coverage -fsanitize=address -lcriterion

# Detect all regular subdirectories in the current directory
SUBDIRS := $(filter-out . .., $(wildcard */.))

# Define phony targets
.PHONY: all clean format library debug functional $(SUBDIRS)

# Rule to build 'all' target in each subdirectory
$(SUBDIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@ all

# Extract target and subdirectory from command line input
ifneq ($(filter %:%,$(MAKECMDGOALS)), $(MAKECMDGOALS))
    @echo "In the donction"
    SUBDIR_TARGET := $(subst :, ,$(MAKECMDGOALS))
    SUBDIR := $(word 1,$(SUBDIR_TARGET))
    SUB_TARGET := $(word 2,$(SUBDIR_TARGET))
    $(MAKE) -C $(SUBDIR) $(SUB_TARGET)
endif
```

When trying to run make subdirectory:subrule I obtain the following error:
`make: *** No rule to make target 'beware_overflow:format'.  Stop.`

Here is the documentation of the submakefile:

```
# Makefile for Project
#
# This Makefile provides rules for building, testing, and cleaning the project.
#
# Generic Rules:
#   - %.o : %.c                         : Compile .c files into object files.
#   - $(LIBRARY_FILE) : $(SOURCE_OBJECTS)   : Create static library from object files.
#   - $(CURRENT_DIR) : format library   : Compile main program.
#
# Standard Rules:
#   - all        : Builds the main program and creates the library.
#   - clean      : Removes generated files and executables.
#   - format     : Formats the source code using clang-format.
#   - library    : Creates a static library from object files.
#   - check      : Compiles and runs tests using Criterion framework.
#   - debug      : Compiles the program with debug symbols and opens in gdb.
#   - functional : Runs shell script tests and generates coverage reports.
```

Comment: Target names containing colons (e.g. `subdir_name:clean`) are a poor design choice because the colon is significant to `make` for separating a rule's target list from its prerequisite list.  But maybe that's moot, because it's *also* a poor choice to try to expose targets in subdirectory makefiles directly to the user running the top-level `make`.  If you *really* want to jump straight to subdirectory targets, however, then you already have that in the form of  `make -C subdir_name clean`.

Comment: Your code seems to suppose that at most one target will be designated explicitly on the command line.  That's within your control as the user, but it is in no way a limitation of `make`.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @John Bollinger, I changed my format to `make subdirectory rule`. I reckon it limits the potential of `make` but considering my current (very limited) knowledge of `make` if found out the following solution:

```
# Documentation for the Makefile
# ------------------------------
# Usage:
# - To build 'all' target in all subdirectories: make
# - To invoke a specific target in all subdirectory: make [target]
#   Example: make clean
# - To invoke a specific target in a specific subdirectory: make [subdirectory]:[target]
#   Example: make subdir_name:clean

# Compiler for project
CC = gcc

# Compiler flags used when compiling every binary or library
CFLAGS = -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -D_GNU_SOURCE

# Compiler flags used when compiling tests
DFLAGS = -lgcov -fPIC -g3 --coverage -fsanitize=address -lcriterion

# Detect all regular subdirectories in the current directory
SUBDIRS := $(filter-out . .., $(wildcard */.))

# Define phony targets
.PHONY: all clean check format library debug functional $(SUBDIRS)

ifndef SINGLE_GOAL
ifneq ($(words $(MAKECMDGOALS)),2)
SINGLE_GOAL := true
endif
endif

# Rule to build 'all' target in each subdirectory
all:
ifdef SINGLE_GOAL
    @for DIR in $(SUBDIRS); do \
        if [ -f $$DIR/Makefile ]; then \
            $(MAKE) -C $$DIR $@; \
        fi \
    done
endif
# Rule to build a specific target in each subdirectory
clean format check library debug functional:
ifdef SINGLE_GOAL
    @for DIR in $(SUBDIRS); do \
        if [ -f $$DIR/Makefile ]; then \
            $(MAKE) -C $$DIR $@; \
        fi \
    done
endif

# Extract target and subdirectory from command line input
% %:
ifndef SINGLE_GOAL
    $(MAKE) -C $(word 1 $(MAKECMDGOALS)) $(word 2 $(MAKECMDGOALS))
endif
```

I have been reading the [GNU `make` documentation](https://devdocs.io/gnu_make/) more closely and I will try to improve my Makefile so it can respect standards and use the full potential of `make`.
Since I don't have the time to dive in further, I'll post a better version later.

Comment: erratum: i just traded a problem for another since with this solution command is launched in every subdirectory in addition to the one specified

Comment: fixed: detection of one/zero goals as opposed to two goals

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this.  The syntax for making one of the subdirectories isn't great and can probably be improved.  It would be `beware_overflow/format.subdir`.

```
SUBDIRS := $(filter-out . .., $(wildcard */.))
SUBDIRS := $(SUBDIRS:/.=)

ALLSUBDIR := $(foreach dir,$(SUBDIRS),$(dir)/all.subdir)

all: $(ALLSUBDIR)
        @echo Made all in subdirs: $(SUBDIRS)

%.subdir:
        @echo $(MAKE) -C $(word 1,$(subst /, ,$*)) $(word 2,$(subst /, ,$*))
```

Example if there are subdirs `foo` and `bar`:

```bash
$ make all foo/whatever.subdir
make -C bar all
make -C foo all
Made all in subdirs: bar foo
make -C foo whatever
```

Basically we make a pattern rule that will match the targets for the subdir/target combo.  It extracts the subdir and sub-target using text parsing from the target's name.  To make `all` in every subdir, we add dependencies for `foo/all.subdir`, `bar/all.subdir`, and so on for every subdir to the `all` target.